# Css issue bars to move left to right on percentage bassis

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a graoh to show positive and negative value by percentage so if value will be negative it will be red bar if value will be positive it will run red bar so the thing is that I am having issue when I set width to 46 or 50% the bar is showing to be of full size as it shouldn't be can anyone help me out with this please

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #333
}

.bar_red {
  background-color: #d40216 !important;
  left: 50%;
  width: 13%;
  max-width: 180px;
}

.bar_green {
  right: 50%;
}

.bar_green,
.bar_red {
  width: 42%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #88c500;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="bar_red" style="width: 50%;"></div>
  <div class="bar_green" style="width: 50%;"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vck8wchh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your bars are pulled 50%. see example below

```
.bar_green {
   right: 50%;
}
.bar_red {
   left: 50%;
}
```

So this means that if you fill in 50% or higher in your `<div style="50%">` it will be full width. Go to your fiddle and for example replace your HTML with the following:

```
<div class="box">
<div class="bar_red" style="width: 10%;"></div>
<div class="bar_green" style="width: 30%;"></div>
</div>
```

You'll see that they won't be fully filled. new [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gmpw831v/1/)

Comment: so is there a way I can make filed up 100% by setting max with ? as I am trying to do max with but it is not working

Comment: Edit the percentages in the div style to 100%. You'll see the page will be fully filled. By adding a max-width 100% you can control the fact that it will never be over 100%.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a simpler solution? In my snippet the green bar is 100% wide, while the red bar gets a percentage width, is right-aligned and covers the green one using a higher `z-index`. So you only have to set the percentage of the red bar.

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 390px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #333;
  border: 5px solid #333;
}

.bar_green,
.bar_red {
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
}

.bar_green {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #88c500;
  z-index: 1;
}

.bar_red {
  background-color: #d40216 !important;
  right: 0;
  width: 42%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="bar_red"></div>
  <div class="bar_green"></div>
</div>
```